# js add event listener not working

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

I am trying to load interactivly some questins from questions' array (q) into my page and after student clicks at one of the 2 questions register the answer and change the question using js while loop. What is my mistake that it doesn't work?

```
var q = [
  ['NFR', 'Reusability'],
  ['NFR', 'Robustness'],
  ['FR', 'Reporting Requirements'],
  ['FR', 'Historical Data']
];

var correct = 0;
var incorrect = 0;
var total = q.length;
var i = 0;

document.getElementById('nick').innerText = name;
document.getElementById('question').innerText = q[0][1];

var nfr = document.getElementById('non-functional');
var fr = document.getElementById('functional');

function callback(ans) {
  if (q[i][0] === ans) {
    correct++;
  } else {
    incorrect++;
  };
  if (i < q.length - 1) {
    i++;
    document.getElementById('question').innerText = q[i][1];
  } else {
    location.href = "answer.html";
  }
}

nfr.addEventListener('click', callback('NFR'));
fr.addEventListener('click', callback('FR'));
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? What behaviour do you expect and what is the result currently?

Comment: 1. it is not changing the qustion
2. it seems not registering the click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop is looping endlessly, because the only thing it does logically is set `toNext` to False, set some event listener callbacks and then evaluate `toNext` again, which will always be False. So `i++` will never be called and `i < q.length` will always be True.

Get rid of the while loop. Write a separate function that evaluates the answer and updates your window with the next question. Use that function as callback for the `click` events.
In a callback function `this` will be set to  the object calling the function, so you could write a function like this:

```
function callback() {
    if (this.id == q[i][0]) {
        window.correct++;
    } else {
        window.incorrect++;
    }

    i++;

    set_question(i); // Logic to set the i-th question.
}
```

---

**Edit**

```
function callback(ans) {
    // This function will return 
    // another function with the ans 
    // variable set, which in turn 
    // will be called as a callback 
    // when needed by the 'click' event.
    return function () {
        if (q[i][0] === ans) {
            correct++;
        } else {
            incorrect++;
        };

        if (i < q.length - 1) {
            i++;
            document.getElementById('question').innerText = q[i][1];
        } else {
            location.href = "answer.html";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's done, I was writing the callback function with () and it was not working

Comment: You could use the function like you would in your edited code, by using closures. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Event listeners are executed asynchronously and the code you write might assumes that the listeners can block loop execution. 
To fix this, try removing the loop and move the logic of switching to the next question into the listener callback.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be better way, however it didn't help. I edited the question after I changed the code.